# Get selected item (aria-selected="true" ) with jquery

Tags: jquery

Hello how get text "ITEM 2" from my example? This is selected item aria-selected="true". Something like this:

```js
var ele = $("body").find("[aria-selected='true']").text();
alert(ele) //alert return empty
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="t-TreeNav lto17215280388447201528_0 a-TreeView" id="t_TreeNav" data-id="32_tree" role="tree" aria-hidden="false" style="visibility: inherit;">
  <ul role="group">
    <li id="t_TreeNav_0" class="a-TreeView-node is-expandable a-TreeView-node--topLevel">
      <div class="a-TreeView-row" />
      <span class="a-TreeView-toggle" />
      <div class="a-TreeView-content">
        <span class="fa fa fa-home" />
        <a tabindex="-1" role="treeitem" class="a-TreeView-label" href="f?p=32794:1:106127592850850::NO:::" aria-level="1" aria-selected="false" aria-expanded="false">Home</a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li id="t_TreeNav_19" class="a-TreeView-node a-TreeView-node--leaf a-TreeView-node--topLevel">
      <div class="a-TreeView-row" />
      <div class="a-TreeView-content">
        <span class="fa fa-file-o" />
        <a tabindex="-1" role="treeitem" class="a-TreeView-label" href="f?p=32794:31:106127592850850::NO:::" aria-level="1" aria-selected="false">ITEM 1</a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li id="t_TreeNav_20" class="a-TreeView-node a-TreeView-node--leaf a-TreeView-node--topLevel">
      <div class="a-TreeView-row is-selected is-current--top" />
      <div class="a-TreeView-content is-selected is-current--top">
        <span class="fa fa-file-o" />
        <a tabindex="0" role="treeitem" class="a-TreeView-label" href="f?p=32794:32:106127592850850::NO:::" aria-level="1" aria-selected="true">ITEM 2</a>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code works as it is - as you can see from the snippet I edited in to the question

Comment: That should work. You could even simplify the selector `$('[aria-selected="true"]').text()`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan  I'm use your example but get empty alert. Without .text()  get object.object.

Comment: I haven't given you an example - it's the same code you posted in the question. If it's not working for you then there's an inconsistency between your code and what's in the question. Without seeing the code that creates the problem we can't really help.